# curl to python for post request

Tags: python, curl, urllib

I would like to "translate" my curl request into python using request or urllib.

I try to post a file.

My curl request is :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Authorization: Bearer $1" -F "data=@$2;filename=$3" --cert certificateprivate.pem --cacert MyDigiCertSHA2.crt.pem <my_url>
```

I tried the code below ( doesn't work , response 400)

```
def upload_file(token,file_path):
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH,cafile='MyDigiCertSHA2.crt.pem')
    ctx.load_cert_chain(certfile='certificateprivate.pem')
    url = <my_url>
    hdr = {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data","Authorization":"Bearer "+token}
    data = '{"filterList":[{}]}'
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        from urllib import request, parse
        data = parse.urlencode( {'filename':file_path,"data": f.read()}).encode()
        req = request.Request( url, data = data,headers=hdr)  
        resp = request.urlopen(req, context=ctx)
        content = resp.read()
        data = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
        print(data)
```

Comment: Sorry for the intention of the python code, I didn't figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: worth checking out: https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

The curl command has `"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"`, but your python code has `"Content-Type": "application/json"`.

Comment: I edited the post, and use "multipart/form-data", I still have the same issue.

Comment: @user5023028 Don't use `parse.urlencode()`. This is only needed for `params` in a GET request.

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html : "For an HTTP POST request method, data should be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The urllib.parse.urlencode() "

Comment: @user5023028 Thanks for the info. I stand corrected. I'm not sure what the problem is now.